# The number of elements in the select list exceeds the maximum allowed number of 4096 elements azure SQL

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

Environment = Microsoft Azure SQL Database

I have dynamic query which has more than 4096 columns in select statement and I am getting this error while executing this.

> The number of elements in the select list exceeds the maximum allowed number of 4096 elements.

I can't reduce the number of columns per select statement. Is there any way to increase the limit of columns per select statement in azure SQL database.?

[sql error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XIZ3Y.png)

Comment: What are you planning to do with that many columns? This just screams bad design. Without details what you are trying to do, and how you are approaching the problem, it is very difficult to answer your question

Comment: No. This [limit is in the SQL Server engine itself](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/maximum-capacity-specifications-for-sql-server#-objects) and not specific to Azure. To be fair, if you need more than 4096 columns you're absolutely doing it wrong. Consider returning the result set rows as (for example) XML or JSON, but of course only after reconsidering the way queries like these end up existing in the first place. I doubt it's something you *can't* do, just that it may result in some uncomfortable rewrites.

Comment: If you have that many columns you're going to have a lot of problems. Your schema design can likely be improved to avoid this. Consider asking a question about that.

Answer (score 1):

How many columns do you need?
There's no way a query and it's index can be optimized across 4K+ columns, it defeats the purpose of storing it in a relational database.
Try get your required columns list down to a smaller number.
If you need more than this try storing your data in a more appropriate environment like a key-value store.